# Please specify a valid grid column alias name that exists in grid table

Tags: grid, magento-ce

Simply trying to create a backend Order in a fresh Magento CE 1.9.2.2 site. All I have done is install a PO Management Module, and imported some products.

Pretty much stumped as Googling the exact error returns few results.